# how to open multiple camera python

Tags: python, opencv, camera

i try to open 4 camera on my jetson-nano but it open 2 camera how can i fix it to show 4 camera ?

i don,t know about python to much please help me

this is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap3 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
cap4 = cv2.VideoCapture(4)

while (True):

    ret0, frame1 = cap1.read()
    ret1, frame2 = cap2.read()
    ret2, frame3 = cap3.read()
    ret3, frame4 = cap4.read()

    if (ret0):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('frame1',gray)

    if (ret1):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('frame2',gray)

    if (ret2):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('frame3',frame)

    if (ret3):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame4, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        cv2.imshow('frame4',frame)

    if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q')):
        break

cap1.release()
cap2.release()
cap3.release()
cap4.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, this will help you. thanks. https://github.com/mrxmamun/multiple-camera-stream